# Pivoting and melting, multiple header column to row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file, with a table like this

```
                             1/1/2017           3/4/2017
                             2/2/2018           5/6/2018
Group   ID    SecID  ISIN    a        b   c     a         b   c  ... 
xxxx    xx    xxxx   xxxx    x        x   x     x         x  x
```

As you can see in the above table, the first four are okay, but the columns a, b, c have a two upper header. I want to add two new columns `start` and `end` along with the columns a, b, c and put the first two header data in to start and end column.

Please note the first two rows dates are associated with the column 'a' in header.

So it should look like this :

```
 Group   ID    SecID  ISIN  start        end       a  b  c
 xxxx    xxx    xxx    xxx   1/1/2017    2/2/2018  x  x  x 
 xxxx    xxx    xxx    xxx   3/4/2017    5/6/2018  x  x  x
```

yes duplicate records will be created, can I get a solution for this?
my import code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv('test.csv',header=[0,1,2])
```

I tried melting it,

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Group", "Id","ISIN","SecId"],
                  var_name="Others", value_name="Value")
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: try `xtab.columns.names = ['start', 'end']; tidy = xtab.stack().stack()` --

Comment: can you give the syntax according to the above code, can what does the second line of code mean, did not work, shows error.

Comment: copy and paste the first ten lines of your CSV into the question

Comment: okay i solved the question using simple csv library, but i could not solve it using pandas. it is still a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `stack`, `reset_index` and `rename`:

```
df = df.set_index(['Group','ID','SecID','ISIN'])
df.stack([0,1]).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_4':'start','level_5':'end'})
```

Comment: could nt get it to work, i get key error.my actual header is in row 3, and date are in row 0 and 1.

Comment: @Zaiku197212 Can you update the question with the actual dataframe structure and maybe 10 rows of data?

Comment: @Zaiku197212 is your key error due to the 'ID' vs 'Inception Date' in your csv file?  You can change the set_index line to df.set_index(['Group','Inception Date','SecId','ISIN']) to match your csv file given on google drive.

Comment: i updated the csv file with original rows and column, please check on the above link. jus in case : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3RtWlE-R7ciOHpjaGVLOHhYOEE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: no , i added the correct name in my code but still it is not working.