# Melt a DataFrame with multiple headers into a normalized format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have Excel data like this. I want to insert it to RDB after converting this to a normalized format. The first header means date, the second one means some category or type. The values means the count of each types.

[image: Origin]

So the output format is going to look like this.

[image: Target]

I can read the original data into DataFrame by the following code, but it does not seem there is a easy way to unpivot a DataFrame with multiple headers.

```
df = pd.read_excel('original_data.xlsx', header=[1,2])
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025821/pivoting-and-melting-multiple-header-column-to-row), but it does not seem to work correctly.

Is there any magics to process this pivot table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I re-created your data (Next time provide data not an image) and did this:

```
import pandas as pd
# Read the file
df = pd.read_excel(r'Data/Stackoverflow_04_25.xlsx',  header=[0,1])
# 'break' the levels in the colum names
df.columns = ['_'.join(col)for col in df.columns]
# Rename some of the columns
df = df.rename(columns = {'ID_Unnamed: 0_level_1':'ID','COUNTRY _Unnamed: 1_level_1':'Country','NAME_Unnamed: 2_level_1':'Name'})
# Generate a new 'final' dataframe
df_ = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ID', 'Country', 'Name'])
# loop over the columns of interes an add the result to the final df
for column in ['4/1_Type2', '4/1_Type3' ,   '4/2_Type1',    '4/2_Type2' ,'4/2_Type3']:
    df1 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Country', 'Name'], as_index = False)[column].first().rename(columns = {column:'Counts'})
    df1.loc[:,'Date'] = column[:3]
    df1.loc[:,'Type'] = column[-5:]
    df_ = pd.concat([df_, df1], 0, sort = True).reset_index(drop = True)
# Order the final dataframe columns
df_ = df_[['ID', 'Country', 'Name', 'Type', 'Date', 'Counts']]
df_
```

Which looks pretty similar to what you want. Hope this works.

```
    ID  Country Name    Type    Date    Counts
0   1   A   D   Type2   4/1 0.0
1   2   B   E   Type2   4/1 0.0
2   3   C   F   Type2   4/1 5.0
3   1   A   D   Type3   4/1 10.0
4   2   B   E   Type3   4/1 5.0
5   3   C   F   Type3   4/1 15.0
6   1   A   D   Type1   4/2 10.0
7   2   B   E   Type1   4/2 10.0
8   3   C   F   Type1   4/2 10.0
9   1   A   D   Type2   4/2 0.0
10  2   B   E   Type2   4/2 10.0
11  3   C   F   Type2   4/2 10.0
12  1   A   D   Type3   4/2 0.0
13  2   B   E   Type3   4/2 0.0
14  3   C   F   Type3   4/2 10.0
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked fine! Btw, why do you use df.groupby()[column], instead not just df[column] ? I think the latter works in the same way.

Comment: @Taichi You are welcome, and YES, in this case it should work the same. I was not sure if you had duplicates.

Comment: Thank you! It seems `df.columns = ['_'.join(col)for col in df.columns]` was the magic to me.